# How to access & populate dropdown when dropdown wildcard id is stored in varibale

Tags: jquery, combobox

in my case i have common routine which populate dropdown and when i am calling that routine then i am passing dropdown wild card id to that routine like this way

### calling this way

```
populateDropwDown(0, 15, '$("select[id*=cboEarlyColHrs]")', '09');

    function populateDropwDown(startIdx, LastIdx, targetid, selectedVal) {
        var listItems = '';
        $(targetid).html("");
        for (var i = startIdx; i <= LastIdx; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                if (i == selectedVal)
                    listItems += "<option value='" + selectedVal + "'>00</option>";
                else
                    listItems += "<option value='00'>00</option>";
            }
            else {
                var ValueHrs = '', TxtData = '';
                ValueHrs = convertDateTo12Hrs(i, true);
                TxtData = convertDateTo12Hrs(i, false);

                if (TxtData == selectedVal)
                    listItems += "<option value='" + ValueHrs + "' option:selected>'" + TxtData + "'</option>";
                else
                    listItems += "<option value='" + ValueHrs + "'>'" + TxtData + "'</option>";
            }
        }
        $(targetid).html(listItems);
    }
```

my main problem is that this line is not working `$(targetid).html(listItems);` this line is `$(targetid).html(listItems);` suppose to re-fill my dropdown but this line is not working.

please guide me when any wildcard id is stored in variable then how could i use that variable to re-fill my dropdown......any idea would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in a jQuery call to select an element, but as a string so it won't work like that.  It would be a lot tidier to pass in *just* the wildcard part of the ID and find it in the function, like this...

```
populateDropwDown(0, 15, 'cboEarlyColHrs', '09');

function populateDropwDown(startIdx, LastIdx, targetid, selectedVal) {
    var listItems = '';
    var $target = $("select[id*=" + targetid + "]");
    $target.html("");
    for (var i = startIdx; i <= LastIdx; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (i == selectedVal)
                listItems += "<option value='" + selectedVal + "'>00</option>";
            else
                listItems += "<option value='00'>00</option>";
        }
        else {
            var ValueHrs = '', TxtData = '';
            ValueHrs = convertDateTo12Hrs(i, true);
            TxtData = convertDateTo12Hrs(i, false);

            if (TxtData == selectedVal)
                listItems += "<option value='" + ValueHrs + "' option:selected>'" + TxtData + "'</option>";
            else
                listItems += "<option value='" + ValueHrs + "'>'" + TxtData + "'</option>";
        }
    }
    $target.html(listItems);
}
```

I also created the `$target` variable so you don't have to search for the same element twice.